# Django Using ManyToMany from the other side instead of ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

In a specific Django app, I have a DB Model class `A` that is considered as the main class and many other models are connected to it weather through one to one relationship (like `B`) or one to many relationship (like `C`). So, the direct approach to implement such is:

```
class A(Model):
    b = OneToOneField('B', on_delete=CASCADE)
    # other fields

class B(Model):
    # some fields

class C(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A, on_delete=CASCADE)
    # other fields
```

Now, when I want to create a new object of `A`, the sequence will be:

- create `B` object
- create `A` object and link the created `B` object to it
- create `C` object and link the created `A` object to it.

This happens on a larger scale with a lot of models linked with model `A`. But I want to have all the relations seen in the `A` class so that when I want to create an object of `A`, I go to create all the related objects first after validating them regardless the relationship, then create new `A` object and link all those related objects to it. So, I did so:

```
class A(Model):
    b = OneToOneField('B', on_delete=CASCADE)
    c = ManyToManyField('C')                      # as there is no OneToManyField

class B(Model):
    # some fields

class C(Model):
    # some fields
```

But this solution seems not good as `C` should have only one `A` object.

Is it acceptable to do this or is there another good practice approach to do?

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany is equal to ForeignKey constructor.

```
class A(Model):
    b = OneToOneField('B', on_delete=CASCADE)
    c = Foreignkey('C', on_delete=CASCADE)

class B(Model):
    # some fields

class C(Model):
    # some fields
```

seems totally fine approach to me.

Comment: ForeignKey is equal to ManyToOne not OneToMany .. unfortunately, your answer is totally incorrect. Your answer mean that class `A` has one of class `C`, however it should have many of class `C`.